# Blocking all trafic except legitimate router

Tags: mac-address, ebtables

In the business centre where I work, all clients are on the same network.

The Internet <--> building router <--> building network (including rogue DHCP, etc) <--> my router's WAN port <--> my router's LAN port <--> my office network

I have my own router in my office that runs OpenWRT so has `iptables` and `ebtables` is available but not installed.

We're sure there is a rogue DHCP server somewhere on the building's network and, perhaps, other "dubious" devices.

Is there a rule I can add to `ebtables` on my router's outgoing port to ignore all trafic that's come from or through any MAC except the "legitimate" external/gateway router?

I'm quite capable of adding a rule to iptables but a little lost when it comes to authoring them and I've only just discovered `ebtables`. I'm "only" a programmer not a "real" network admin.

Comment: Don't attempt to solve problems that should not exist. Go to the building manager and demand the order and security in the upstream network.

Comment: *all clients on the same network*, *rogue DHCP server somewhere*, *dubious devices* would need to be addressed by separating your network from the building network. Anything else is patchwork.

Comment: The external network should apply client isolation, so that you don't see other customers.

Comment: The WAN interface of the router is likely not attached to a bridge. In that case to use ebtables (for blocking WAN side traffics) you will first need to create a new bridge and enslave the WAN interface to it. (Don't enslave it to the LAN side bridge, if any.) Note that there would be quite a lot to adjust if you insist. For example, you'll need to "move" the IP configuration to the bridge. iptables rules will need to be adjusted since now you will need to match with the interface name of the bridge instead.

Comment: You may want to see if your DHCP client allows you to blacklist and/or whitelist server instead. (Although they seem to be IP-based, if supported at all.)

Comment: @TomYan - Yes, trying something at the DHCP client level was the first thing I tried. :(